# Jagged array versus one big array?

Tags: c#, chess

Not so sure how to ask this question, but I have 2 ways (so far) for a lookup array

Option 1 is:

```
bool[][][] myJaggegArray;

myJaggegArray = new bool[120][][];
for (int i = 0; i < 120; ++i)
{
  if ((i & 0x88) == 0)
  {
    //only 64 will be set
    myJaggegArray[i] = new bool[120][];
    for (int j = 0; j < 120; ++j)
    {
      if ((j & 0x88) == 0)
      {
        //only 64 will be set
        myJaggegArray[i][j] = new bool[60];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Option 2 is:

```
bool[] myArray;
//                [998520]
myArray = new bool[(120 | (120 << 7) | (60 << 14))];
```

Both ways work nicely, but is there another (better) way of doing a fast lookup and which one would you take if speed / performance is what matter?

This would be used in a [chessboard implementation (0x88)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Board_representation_%28chess%29#0x88_method) and mostly is

`[from][to][dataX]` for option 1

`[(from | (to << 7) | (dataX << 14))]` for option 2

Comment: I'd take whichever option is easiest to use & read. You can always optimize later, when your code is finished and you feel like it should be faster than it already is.

Comment: @Nolonar, in fact, i'm at the point now

Comment: I would use one large array WITH a getter method with all three parameters. Both fast, readable, and allows for simple future changes.

Comment: @Nolonar: It's chess. You know that it will not be fast enough before you write the first line of code. You *always* need more performance in chess.

Comment: What's the story with numbers 0x88, 120 and 60?

Comment: @Dialecticus, mostly, it is easier to check boundary and other things, for more detail it would be better to look on site that have pages and pages to describe it. this comment box is too small :-)

Comment: why using array of booleans when it have to be optimized? you can have a 2-dimensional array of longs instead (long can hold up to 64 booleans with '(value & (1 << index)) == 0')

Comment: It could be that many a theory behind chessboard implementation practices is invalid when translated to C#. .NET hides all kinds of complexities from you (GC, bounds checking), but those complexities have a big influence on time critical code. You just have to stress-test all the alternatives.

Comment: @sasjaq, hmm your right I will test that tonight

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using one large array, because of the advantages of having one large memory block, but I would also encourage writing a special accessor to that array.

```
class MyCustomDataStore
{ 
  bool[] array;
  int sizex, sizey, sizez;

  MyCustomDataStore(int x, int y, int z) {
    array=new bool[x*y*z];
    this.sizex = x;
    this.sizey = y;
    this.sizez = z;
  }

  bool get(int px, int py, int pz) {
    // change the order in whatever way you iterate
    return  array [ px*sizex*sizey + py*sizey + pz ];
  }

}
```

Comment: it is easier to read but by looking at IL code(unless jitter does the inlining) this do not get inlined and cost a lot while being in a big loop.

Comment: Agreed, unless inlined the function call may make it much less efficient. Perhaps marking the get method `sealed` may improve the chance.

Comment: quick note, `x*y*z` and `px*sizex*sizey + py*sizey + pz` is wrong, it should be `(x | (y << 7) | (z << 14))` for both without keeping them in local variable.

Answer (score 1):

I just update dariusz's solution with an array of longs for z-size <= 64

edit2: updated to '<<' version, size fixed to 128x128x64

```
class MyCustomDataStore
{
     long[] array;

     MyCustomDataStore() 
     {
          array = new long[128 | 128 << 7];
     }

     bool get(int px, int py, int pz) 
     {
          return (array[px | (py << 7)] & (1 << pz)) == 0;
     }

     void set(int px, int py, int pz, bool val) 
     {
          long mask = (1 << pz);
          int index = px | (py << 7);
          if (val)
          {
               array[index] |= mask;
          }
          else
          {
               array[index] &= ~mask;
          }
     }
}
```

edit: performance test:
used 100 times 128x128x64 fill and read

```
long: 9885ms, 132096B
bool: 9740ms, 1065088B
```

Comment: I will definitively try this tonight

Comment: a quick note like i said for dariusz's solution, doing 120*120*60 then using the same to read the value is wrong for what I said, it should be based on `(x | (y << 7) | (z << 14))`

Comment: i just tried and it make everything a little bit slower than a array of bool